# Azure Application Gateway App Service using Active Directory redirecting to signin-oidc

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have put my app behind azure application gateway. I can access my app using the application gateway through this url: `https://myapps.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/myapp`

My app requires azure ad so I and I am prompted to login (with azure AD), after I login I am redirected to: `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`

But I want my app url to be masked by the gateway name: `https://myapps.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/myapp`

How do I configure my app to be masked by the url, after I sign in through azure AD. I am using a path based rule for my backend pool as /myapp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you want the reply URL for your web app authentication is the `myapps.westus.cloudapp.azure.com` instead of the `*.azurewebsites.net` hostname. Since it's impossible to add the Azure provided DNS name of app gateway as the hostname for your web app, you can do this with a **custom domain**. These will correctly redirect the client browser to the custom domain that routes through the Application Gateway after authenticating. These steps ensure the reply URL is the custom domain and you can still monitor requests through the Application Gateway.

**Main steps**:

1. [Add a custom domain to your web app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).
2. Configure an SSL certificate for the custom domain.
3. Set up Azure Active Directory authentication using the **Authentication / Authorization** feature on the App Service.
4. Configure the proper reply URLs. If you configured your custom domain before setting up Azure Active Directory authentication, both your `*.azurewebsites.net` and custom domain URLs should be configured for the reply URLs. If your custom domain is not there, be sure to set up the reply URL as `https://<custom domain>/.auth/login/aad/callback`.
5. The default configuration for the backend HTTP setting uses `-PickHostNameFromBackendAddress`. By instead, you could use the `-HostName` `<enter your custom domain i.e www.contoso.com>` configuration for the backend HTTP settings.

In the end, browse to your custom domain over HTTPS, login using Azure Active Directory, and you’ll be authenticated to your site over the custom domain. You could refer to this blog: [Setting up Application Gateway with an App Service that uses Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/11/21/setting-up-application-gateway-with-an-app-service-that-uses-azure-active-directory-authentication/)

Comment: You're welcome. You just need a public domain. I think you need to change to use the `-HostName test.com` for the backend HTTP settings when using AAD authentication. Have you checked the steps 4 and 5 in my reply? Also, you can find details from that blog.

Comment: When I add my -HostName test.com to my http setting and I try to access the application gateway, i receive a 502 error. The health probe is healthy so I am not sure.

Comment: Do you have a custom probe (host test.com) matching the Http settings host?

Comment: Yes I did add my custom host to my app service. But then dont I need to point that host to my application gateway after

Comment: I suggest using path-based rule and custom hostname in your backend web app, configure the health probe and HTTP settings for host test.com.

Comment: Yes that works, the problem was that I was using waf v2 tier, and this does not allow to upload .cer certificates and causes problems with changing the httpsetting hostname.

Comment: Wondering how this will work if there are more than one web app that need the OAuth capability and all of them are fronted by the same App Gateway. Not sure how we can have the host name for all the app services